# How to automatically change color of cell if value is changed

Tags: excel, vba

**My issue is the following:**
I have a macro to change the color of specific rows if the value was changed manually. But I can't find a solution on how to automate this process, so that I don't have to press the run button all the time.

**What I have:**

```vb
Sub wrong_value_transfer()
    If Range("b1").Value = "EN Form" Then
        If Range("b11").Value <> "Required field" Then
        Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(38, 201, 218)
        Else: Range("b11").Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does conditional formatting not help?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I agreed with you. OP can do it by CF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("b1").Value = "EN Form" Then
        If Range("b11").Value <> "Required field" Then
            Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(38, 201, 218)
              Else
            Range("b11").Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: You can do it in single IF statement like `If (Range("b1").Value = "EN Form") And (Range("b11").Value <> "Required field") Then`

Comment: Glad to know. Then please accept the answer (tick mark it).